# replace 2 backslashes to one

Tags: java, regex

I went over the questions and couldn't find a solution.

I have properties file where the user stores the location of file.

e.g:

```
location = C:\images
```

In the response to him, I have to printout the location property and it prints it like this:

```
C:images
```

If I put in location:

```
C:\\images\\
```

it prints it like this (as if it didn't processed the string:

```
C:\\images\\
```

I would like it to simply print it `C:\images\`

How can I do it?

This also applies to where I want to write an HTML tag like this:

```
<img src ='"+locations+"'>
```

Most browser would extract the location with double backslashes, but I do not prefer to rely on it.

**EDIT**

I am sorry - my mistake. Now the question is fine. Please ignore the face that C:\ is not accessed by a web browser

**EDIT**

I am using Jerrsey implementation for the client response which are using Jax-B for writing the response like this:

```
    com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(Object t, MediaType mediaType, Charset c, Marshaller m, OutputStream entityStream) throws JAXBException:

 protected void writeTo(Object t, MediaType mediaType, Charset c,
            Marshaller m, OutputStream entityStream)
            throws JAXBException {
        m.marshal(t, entityStream);
    }
```

The output stream is `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.CommittingOutputStream`

I saw that the properties are being loaded with only  1 .

I get the response in my rest client tool from WizTools.org

Could it be the problem?

Comment: Are the slashes the right way around?

Comment: / is a slash, \ is a backslash.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake I edited my quesiton

Comment: I would just use `/` which doesn't have this problem. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape backslashes, but not forward slashes. So if you have a property file of:

```
location = c:\\images\\
```

That should be fine.

For example, here's a small console app:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        // Would normally close the stream, of course :)
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("test.properties"));
        System.out.println(properties.getProperty("location"));
    }
}
```

Given a test.properties file which *just* contains the line shown earlier, that prints out `c:\images\` with no problems.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake. I meant local location. Please ignore the fact that C:\ will not be accessed by the browser

Comment: @Odelya: Okay, I've edited my answer. Basically, you do need to escape backslashes, but you don't need to escape forward slashes. That's as far as the *property* is concerned. What you want in the *HTML* is potentially a different matter.

Comment: @Odelya: Did you try the code I included in my answer? I'd be very surprised if that behaved differently for you. How are you looking at the string? If you're viewing it in a debugger, it may be escaping the value for you when you're inspecting it - I'd recommend writing it to the console, as my sample does. If you're loading the properties in a different way, please give details. Basically, the code I've given *does* work, so we need to know how where the difference is...

Comment: I am using this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/PropertyLoader.htm property loader to load the properties

Comment: @Odelya: Okay, well that's just using `Properties.load`, like I am. Did you *try* my code? (Note that the code you've given can leak input stream handles, as the `close` call isn't in a `finally` block. Not a great sample...)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5226/discussion-between-odelya-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: @Odelya: No, chat doesn't work for my workflow. Please keep using comments.

Comment: I get: java.io.FileNotFoundException
in your example
I put the file under src folder
and working with Windows

Comment: @Odelya: Well you need the file to be available from wherever you're *running* the code... I suggest you just compile it and run it from the command line for simplicity.

Comment: What if I want to take the file from classpath?

Comment: @Odelya: Then handle that part separately. You need to work out where the problem's coming from first - whether it's how you're looking at the property value (which you haven't told us) or whether it's how the file is being loaded. This test is just to make sure there's nothing *really* strange going on on your system.

Comment: See my edited answer. maybe it's the Jersey implementation of the response

Comment: @Odelya: Well without knowing anything about Jersey, it's hard to say for sure - but use some logging to prove to yourself that the problem *isn't* in the `Properties.load` part. You still haven't really explained *where* you're seeing doubling. For example, if it's in an AJAX response then it *should* be doubled, because the Javascript code will be performing unescaping too.

Comment: I edited my part. I saw in the properties load - I did sys out and the variable was with on slash. only when I write to the rest tool I get it with double slashes.

Comment: @Odelya: Right, so it could well be that there's actually *nothing* wrong - what format is the REST result in? If it's JavaScript, then this sounds like all is working as it should be, and the value is just being escaped correctly.

Comment: It' good to know. Sorry about the different question - but you mentioned that the property loader is not good. When i try your example - I get filenotfound - how do I tell it to take from src folder?

Comment: @Odelya: You would have to specify the file name relative to your current working directory. All I was saying was that that code could easily leak open `InputStream` objects, due to `close` not being in a finally block.

Answer (score 2):

The use of backslash is error-prone. Please use

```
location=file:/C:/images/
```

or (to suggest its an folder without an trailed "/" )

```
directory=file:/C:/images
```

Regards

Comment: Well, your answer will solve this problem. But not a solution in general to backslashes!

Comment: Thats right. It solves the problem and points to an more stable alternate. Regexp, Beanshell and webbrowsers may be happy to work with / instead of \.  :D

Answer (score 2):

The specification for the format of a Java properties file is in the javadoc for the [`Properties.load(Reader)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) method.  It clearly states that a backslash *must* be escaped.  It also states that a backslash that is followed by some character other than valid escapes is *silently dropped*.

I can only conclude that you are not using one of the `load` methods of the `Properties` object to load the properties from your file.  And, in effect, you are not following the Java properties file specification.

You may have some reason to do both of these things, but if you do then you shouldn't be calling your non-standard file format "properties files" ... because people expect Java property files to follow the specification.

---

However, I'd recommend that you just use the standard format / specification, and that you just use `Properties.load(...)` and `Properties.save(...)` to read and write properties files.

Comment: I followed this example: : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/PropertyLoader.htm  as you can see - it's using load

Comment: See my edited answer. maybe it's the Jersey implementation of the response